# Font "AGaramondPro-semibold" cannot be found

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec

I have a document [CV template taken from [Paul Gessler](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/21344/paul-gessler). I am having difficulty finding  AGaramondpro-Semibold font from fontspec package. I have already upgraded the fontspec package from package repositories. I dont have a problem when I replace all the AGaramondPro-Semibold occurances to Georgia.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}

\def\myauthor{Paul Gessler}
\def\mytitle{pdg-vita}
\def\myemail{paul.gessler@marquette.edu}
\def\myweb{pdgessler}
\def\myphone{414-241-1627}
\def\mykeywords{
  paul gessler, 
  resume, 
  curriculum, 
  vita, 
  curriculum vita, 
  cv, 
  paul, 
  gessler, 
  pdg
}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\newenvironment{itemize*}%
{\begin{itemize}%
  \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}}%
{\end{itemize}}

\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}
%\usepackage{ocgtools}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist{nolistsep,leftmargin=0.15in}
\usepackage[log-declarations=false]{xparse}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[margin=1.125in,right=1in,left=2in]{geometry}
\usepackage[strict]{changepage}
\usepackage[
  ocgcolorlinks,
  urlcolor={[rgb]{0,0,0.54}},
  unicode,
  plainpages=false,
  pdfpagelabels,
  pdftitle={\mytitle},
  pdfauthor={\myauthor},
  pdfkeywords={\mykeywords}
]{hyperref}

% fix ocgcolor link breaking; thanks due to Benjamin Lerner (http://goo.gl/VZKR7M)
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \newlength{\temp@x}%
  \newlength{\temp@y}%
  \newlength{\temp@w}%
  \newlength{\temp@h}%
  \def\my@coords#1#2#3#4{%
    \setlength{\temp@x}{#1}%
    \setlength{\temp@y}{#2}%
    \setlength{\temp@w}{#3}%
    \setlength{\temp@h}{#4}%
    \adjustlengths{}%
    \my@pdfliteral{\strip@pt\temp@x\space\strip@pt\temp@y\space\strip@pt\temp@w\space\strip@pt\temp@h\space re}}%
  \ifpdf
    \typeout{In PDF mode}%
    \def\my@pdfliteral#1{\pdfliteral page{#1}}% I don't know why % this command...
    \def\adjustlengths{}%
  \fi
  \ifxetex
    \def\my@pdfliteral #1{\special{pdf: literal direct #1}}% isn't equivalent to this one
    \def\adjustlengths{\setlength{\temp@h}{-\temp@h}\addtolength{\temp@y}{1in}\addtolength{\temp@x}{-1in}}%
  \fi%
  \def\Hy@colorlink#1{%
    \begingroup
      \ifHy@ocgcolorlinks
        \def\Hy@ocgcolor{#1}%
        \my@pdfliteral{q}%
        \my@pdfliteral{7 Tr}% Set text mode to clipping-only
      \else
        \HyColor@UseColor#1%
      \fi
  }%
  \def\Hy@endcolorlink{%
    \ifHy@ocgcolorlinks%
      \my@pdfliteral{/OC/OCPrint BDC}%
      \my@coords{0pt}{0pt}{\pdfpagewidth}{\pdfpageheight}%
      \my@pdfliteral{F}% Fill clipping path (the url's text) with current color
      \my@pdfliteral{EMC/OC/OCView BDC}%
      \begingroup%
        \expandafter\HyColor@UseColor\Hy@ocgcolor%
        \my@coords{0pt}{0pt}{\pdfpagewidth}{\pdfpageheight}%
        \my@pdfliteral{F}% Fill clipping path (the url's text) with \Hy@ocgcolor
      \endgroup%
      \my@pdfliteral{EMC}%
      \my@pdfliteral{0 Tr}% Reset text to normal mode
      \my@pdfliteral{Q}%
    \fi
    \endgroup
  }%
}
\makeatother
% end fixes

\newcommand{\ML}{\textsc{Matlab}}
\newcommand{\Simu}{Simulink}
\newcommand{\MLS}{\ML{}/\Simu{}}
\newcommand{\apdl}{\textsc{APDL}}
\newcommand{\ansys}{\textsc{Ansys}}
\newcommand{\fluent}{\textsc{Fluent}}
\newcommand\CPP{C/C\ensuremath{+}\ensuremath{+}}
\newcommand{\Star}{\textsc{Star-CCM\ensuremath{+}}}

\newcommand{\mhead}[1]{\leavevmode\marginpar{\sffamily\footnotesize #1}}
\newcommand{\rdate}[1]{{\addfontfeature{Numbers=OldStyle} \hfill #1}}
\renewcommand{\date}[1]{{\addfontfeature{Numbers=OldStyle} #1}}
\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{-} 

\setmainfont[
  Ligatures={TeX,Common},
  BoldFont={AGaramondPro-Semibold},
]{Adobe Garamond Pro}
\setsansfont[
  Ligatures={TeX,Common},
  Letters=SmallCaps,
  Color=660000,
]{Adobe Garamond Pro}
\setmonofont{FontAwesome}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{fancy} \setlength\headwidth{6.5in}
\rhead{\textsc{paul d.~gessler—r\'{e}sum\'{e}—\thepage{} of \pageref*{LastPage}}} \cfoot{}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{adjustwidth}{-1in}{}
{\Huge
  {\textsc{%
    {\addfontfeature{Style=TitlingCaps}P}\kern-1.5ptaul 
    {\addfontfeature{Style=TitlingCaps}D}\kern-2pt.~%
    {\addfontfeature{Style=TitlingCaps}G}essler}
  }
}
\hfill\hfill\hfill
{
  \begin{minipage}[b]{1.6in}
    \flushleft \footnotesize 
    2040 West Wisconsin Avenue \\ 
    Apartment S406A \\ 
    Milwaukee, WI~~53233-2098
  \end{minipage}
  \hfill
  \begin{minipage}[b]{1.6in}
    \flushright \footnotesize 
    \href{tel:\myphone}{\myphone} \\ %\texttt{}~
    \href{mailto:\myemail}{\myemail} \\
    \href{https://www.github.com/\myweb}{\texttt{}}~\href{https://www.linkedin.com/in/\myweb}{\texttt{}~\myweb}
  \end{minipage}
}\par
\hrulefill
\end{adjustwidth}  
\reversemarginpar 
\setlength\marginparwidth{0.85in}
\medskip
\mhead{Education}%
\textbf{Marquette University,} Milwaukee, Wisconsin \newline
\emph{Master of Science, \href{http://www.marquette.edu/engineering/mechanical/}{Mechanical Engineering}} \rdate{2012–2014}
\begin{itemize*}
  \item Cumulative GPA: 3.60/4.00; \href{http://www.marquette.edu/engineering/mechanical/grad_study.shtml}{Energy Systems Specialization}
  \item Thesis: One-Dimensional Model of a Refrigeration Cycle Compressor Test Block
  \item Advisor: Dr.~Margaret M.~Mathison
%  \item Coursework:\newline
%    \begin{tabular}{ll}
%      \addlinespace\toprule
%      Advanced Engineering Mathematics & Transport Phenomena \\
%      Approx.~Methods in Engineering Analysis & Advanced Fluid Mechanics \\
%      Intermediate Thermodynamics & Sustainable Engineering \\
%      Statistical Thermodynamics & Combustion \\
%      \bottomrule
%    \end{tabular}
\end{itemize*}

\medskip
\textbf{Milwaukee School of Engineering,} Milwaukee, Wisconsin \newline
\emph{Bachelor of Science, \href{http://www.msoe.edu/community/academics/mechanical-engineering-department/mechanical-engineering}{Mechanical Engineering}} \rdate{2008–2012}
\begin{itemize*}
  \item Cumulative GPA: 3.56/4.00; \href{http://www.msoe.edu/community/academics/minors/page/1448/mathematics-minor}{Mathematics Minor}
  \item Senior Project: \href{https://dl.dropbox.com/u/10724484/resume/ME492_2012_Design_Report_PulseWaterJet.pdf}{Modeling of Pulsed Jet Impingement on Brittle Materials}
  \item Advisors: Prof.~Thomas J.~Labus and Dr.~Vincent C.~Prantil
%  \item Selected Coursework:\newline
%    \begin{tabular}{ll}
%      \addlinespace\toprule
%      
%      \bottomrule
%    \end{tabular}
\end{itemize*}

\end{document}
```

ERROR :

[image: Error related to Fontspec and AGaramondPro-Semibold]

Comment: What do you mean exactly? The font is installed on your system and it doesn't display in your document? How did you declare it to fontspec?

Comment: @Bernard : Please try to run the MWE.

Comment: i don't know about bernard, but there is no point in _me_ trying your mwe, since i only have one "bought" adobe font, and it's not garamond pro<anything>.  where have you installed the font?

Comment: I don't have Adobe Garamond Pro, but I have Minion Pro, which also has a semibold version. I had no problem compiling your code and I could check the resulting pdf does embed the semibold version. So the only explanation is your installation location of your font. If it is known to your system, it will  be accessible to font spec. If it is at the right place in your TeXMF tree (%root/fonts/opentype/) it will also find them provided you've run `ups-sys` (or `updmap`if you use MiKTeX) in order to refresh the fontnames database.

Comment: If the education section of my résumé is to be considered a minimal working example, I must be doing something wrong... `:D` But in seriousness, an appropriate MWE here would be: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[BoldFont={AGaramondPro-Semibold}]{Adobe Garamond Pro}

\begin{document}
  Test rm. \textbf{Test bf.}
\end{document}`

Comment: @Bernard Did you mean `updmap-sys`? That's what I'd use on OS X/Linux. (Although it is new to me that this has anything to do with Xe/LuaTeX finding opentype fonts. I thought `mktexlsr` would be enough for that and that `updmap-sys` updated maps only used by (pdf)TeX.) EDIT: The man page for `updmap-sys` seems pretty clear on this point: 'Update the default font map files used by pdftex, dvips, and dvipdfm(x), and optionally pxdvi, as determined by all configuration files updmap.cfg...'.

Comment: @cfr: Yes, I meant updmap-sys. Sorry for the typo. Actually I don't know how Xe/LuaLaTeX find opent type fonts that are not installed  for the system (I mean the OS), for instance those installed in a TDS. I suppose maybe they use the fontnames database. Anyway, running updmap-sys can do no harm…

Comment: @PaulGessler : also I dont know why you have \setmonofont{FontAwesome}. I see boxed question marks in LinkedIn and GitHub syntax. Why is this? [See my MWE]

Comment: @abhilashsukumari I used this to get FontAwesome symbols (which are the boxed question mark characters). This was created before I knew about the [`fontawesome`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/fontawesome) package, which is a better solution to get these symbols.

Comment: Ah. Ok. I used the package to directly get this. Thank you much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you running Windows? You could try running

`fc-list`

to get a list of the fonts installed on your computer. They should be listed in the format

`<path>:<font names>:<styles>`

eg.

`C:/WINDOWS/fonts/corbelz.ttf: Corbel:style=Bold Italic`

In this case, you could use the font 'Corbel'. As far as I know, you'd have to make sure the font is listed exactly as 'AGaramondPro-Semibold'.

Comment: You can also specify the font's path with `BoldFont=<pathname>` instead of `BoldFont={<fontname>}`.

Answer (score 0):

You’ve run into one of the kind of issue that made Will Robertson [recommend loading fonts by filename.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L0MfY6EkiKc)  XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX use different font loaders and make different guesses what you mean when you tell it to load `Adobe Garamond Pro`.

The quick fix is to try `BoldFont={AGaramondPro-Semibold.otf}`.  I’ve had XeLaTeX choke on things like that, though.  If you get errors about how `AGaramondPro-Semibold.md` does not exist, an ugly workaround might be to add `BoldFeatures = {Extension = .otf}`.

Based on the technical information on fonts.com, you might set up your family this way:

```
\setmainfont[
  Scale = 1.0,
  Ligatures = {Common, TeX},
  Numbers = OldStyle,
  UprightFont = *-Regular ,
  UprightFeatures = {Ligatures = Discretionary},
  BoldFont = *-Semibold ,
  ItalicFont = *-Italic ,
  ItalicFeatures = {Ligatures = Discretionary},
  BoldItalicFont = *-SemiboldItalic ,
  Extension = .otf
]{AGaramondPro}
```

You can also move that setup into a file named `AGaramondPro.fontspec` and be able to update it if you ever buy a new version of the font family.